# How can I use regex to catch unquoted array indices in PHP code and quote them?

Tags: php, regex

PHP 7.2 upgraded undefined constant errors from a notice to a warning, with advice that in future they will return a full-on error instead.

I am trying to identify a way to fix these via scripting, ideally via a regex that I can run to parse each PHP file on a site, find all offending bits of code, and fix them.

I've found multiple examples of how to fix one variant, but none for another, and it's that one that I'm looking for help with.

Here's an example file:

```
<?php

$array[foo] = "bar"; 
// this should become 
// $array['foo'] = "bar"

echo "hello, my name is $array[foo] and it's nice to meet you"; 
// would need to become 
// echo "hello, my name is " . $array['foo'] . " and it's nice to meet you";

?>
```

I've seen a lot of options to identify and change the first type, but none for the second, where the undefined constant is within a string. In that instance the parser would need to:

1. Replace `$array[foo]` with `$array['foo']`
2. Find the entire variable, end quotes beforehand, put a . either side, and then reopen quotes afterwards

Edit: ideally one regexp would deal with both examples in the sample code in one pass - i.e. add the ticks, and also add the quotes/dots if it identifies it’s within a string.

Comment: Could you not grep the entire codebase with something like `\$[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]+\]` ? (based on the RegExp for valid variable names found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $array[foo] = "bar"; 
> // this should become 
> // $array['foo'] = "bar"
> ```

Yes, this has always triggered a notice and has always been poor practice.

> ```
> echo "hello, my name is $array[foo] and it's nice to meet you"; 
> // would need to become 
> // echo "hello, my name is " . $array['foo'] . " and it's nice to meet you";
> ```

No, this style has never triggered a notice and does not now. In fact, [it's used as an example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-53) in the PHP documentation. PHP is never going to remove the ability to interpolate array variables in strings.

---

Your first case is easy enough to catch with something like this:

```
$str = '$array[foo] = "bar";';
echo preg_replace("/(\\$[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)\\[([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\\]/", "$1['$2']", $str);
```

But of course needs to be caught only outside of a string.

As with any complex grammar, regular expressions will never be as reliable as a grammar-specific parser. Since you're parsing PHP code, your most accurate solution will be to use [PHP's own token parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

```
$php = <<< 'PHP'
<?php
$array[foo] = "bar"; // this line should be the only one altered.
$array['bar'] = "baz";
echo "I'm using \"$array[foo]\" and \"$array[bar]\" in a sentence";
echo 'Now I\'m not using "$array[foo]" and "$array[bar]" in a sentence';
PHP;

$tokens = token_get_all($php);
$in_dq_string = false;
$last_token = null;
$output = "";

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($last_token === "[" && is_array($token) && $token[0] === 319 && !$in_dq_string) {
        $output .= "'$token[1]'";
    } elseif (is_array($token)) {
        $output .= $token[1];
    } else {
        if ($token === "\"") {
            $in_dq_string = !$in_dq_string;
        }
        $output .= $token;
    }
    $last_token = $token;
}

echo $output;
```

Output:

```
<?php
$array['foo'] = "bar"; // this line should be the only one altered.
$array['bar'] = "baz";
echo "I'm using \"$array[foo]\" and \"$array[bar]\" in a sentence";
echo 'Now I\'m not using "$array[foo]" and "$array[bar]" in a sentence';
```

This code would need some edge cases accounted for, such as when you are intentionally using a constant as an array index.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I hadn’t seen that bit of documentation so assumed that that would also be invalid. As you suggest, that would indeed mean that any regexp would specifically need to ignore examples inside code, unless they were additionally converted to be outside the string that is!

Comment: I was not aware of token_get_all(). Seems like this is the ideal way to tackle this and much more elegant than regexp!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but it should be safe to run multiple times ([example](https://3v4l.org/2cCvC))

```
$str = 'echo "hello, my name is $array[foo] and it\'s nice to meet you";';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\".*(\$.*\[[^\'].*[^\']\]).*\"/', function($match) {
    $search = ['[', ']'];
    $replace = ["['", "']"];
    $array = '" . ' . str_replace($search, $replace, $match[1]) . ' . "';

    return str_replace($match[1], $array, $match[0]);
}, $str);
```

What the regex does is it limits itself to double quoted strings (`\"`). Then we look for `$var[val]`, without the ticks `'`. Once we've captured it, we can run it through a callback that does a two-stage `str_replace`. The first wraps our matched `$var[val]` with double quotes and inserts the ticks, while the second inserts it into the whole string, using the regex found match

It won't do some things nicely tho. If you have `$array[foo] $array[bar]`, it will wind up as

```
" . $array['foo'] . "" . $array['bar'] . "
```

Not pretty, but still valid code

Comment: Interesting! It does work for that use case but ideally it would be one regexp that would handle both examples 1 and 2 - any thoughts? I guess I could always run this one and then a separate one to catch any further examples that don’t have the ticks, right enough :) (have clarified this in the original question, too)